# How to install Fedora's fedpkg on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

Looking to pull the source code from Fedora to a Ubuntu system and discovered I need to run fedpkg to get the latest source. However I have no idea how to do this on my Ubuntu 10.04 system. Short of spinning up a Fedora instance and then copying across does anyone have and idea on how to solve this issue?

It would appear that installing fedpkg would the obvious but possibly incorrect solution.

EDIT

The reason for wanting the source is to run analysis over it, not to build anything from it or run anything. Specifically I am trying to pull the entire source tree. The reason for wanting the source via GIT/fedpkg is that I can be sure to get the latest and update it fairly easily without resorting to a ISO download extract.

I should mention I am probably going to end up doing this though a virtual machine as it seems less hack, but that there was not even a CLUE on how to do this via any search terms I threw into Google/Bing. It must be possible to bring the package manager across, I just have no idea how to do it or even if its a good idea.

Comment: What package do you need the source for, and is it not packaged in Ubuntu already?

Comment: What exactly are you _really_ trying to do? If it doesn't involve building Fedora or porting source code, you're likely barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get away with downloading the [`fedpkg`](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/fedpkg) RPM, converting it to a Deb using [`alien`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/alien), and then installing that. The success of this will depend on whether the RPM scripts do anything significant, and how many RPM-specific assumptions have been made in the files which the package installs.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to get the source of Fedora on your Ubuntu system, if I understood well?
If so, the easiest is to download it [here](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/source/iso/Fedora-17-source-DVD.iso).

*If you mean that you want to **build Fedora on Ubuntu**, then you will need to install the Fedora packaging tools, which is possible but quite hard to do. It is way easier to install Fedora (for instance in a virtual machine) and build it from there.*